# jquery masonry positioning / overlapping

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a tab div at the top before the divs for masonry
but when i run the code, its going ontop of the tabs and i have no idea
what i can do to try and fix this issue.

```
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#tabs').tab();
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#posts").masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.post',
                    isAnimated: true
                });
        });
```

and this is my div

```
    <div id="posts">
                <div class="post span3">
                    <div><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://reformrevolution.com/wp-content/uploads/rr_20things1.jpg"></img>
                        <h6>The Title of the Picture / Descriptions</h6>
                        </a>
                        <p>---</br>Published by Victor Weng.</br>Date Jan,21,2000</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post span3">
                    <div><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://reformrevolution.com/wp-content/uploads/cities-iv-04.jpg"></img>
                        <h6>The Title of the Picture / Descriptions</h6>
                        </a>
                        <p>---</br>Published by Victor Weng.</br>Date Jan,21,2000</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post span3">
                    <div>
                        <h4> When life gives you a hundred reasons to cry, show life that you have a thousand reasons to smile. </h4>
                        <p>---</br>Published by Victor Weng.</br>Date Jan,21,2000</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
```

this is the tab html code

```
    <div class="row span12 tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#life" data-toggle="tab">Life</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#sci" data-toggle="tab">Science</a></li>  
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="life">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span4">
                                <h3 class="cPink">Life Article Title</h3>
                                <p>Sed bibendum ultricies quam non laoreet. Suspendisse ut odio vitae eros bibendum aliquam. Phasellus quis sapien leo, vel consequat massa. Duis vel suscipit lorem. Nam eu urna id leo molestie ullamcorper eget id eros. Aenean venenatis mattis lorem, a elementum odio accumsan et. Suspendisse cursus metus feugiat tortor molestie vitae porta sapien ultricies. Fusce malesuada sodales commodo. </p>
                                <a class="pull-right" href="#">Read More --></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divider-vertical"></div>
                            <div class="span4">
                                <h3 class="cPink">Life Article Title</h3>
                                <p>Sed bibendum ultricies quam non laoreet. Suspendisse ut odio vitae eros bibendum aliquam. Phasellus quis sapien leo, vel consequat massa. Duis vel suscipit lorem. Nam eu urna id leo molestie ullamcorper eget id eros. Aenean venenatis mattis lorem, a elementum odio accumsan et. Suspendisse cursus metus feugiat tortor molestie vitae porta sapien ultricies. Fusce malesuada sodales commodo. </p>
                                <a class="pull-right" href="#">Read More --></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divider-vertical"></div>
                            <div class="span4">
                                <h3 class="cPink">Life Article Title</h3>
                                <p>Sed bibendum ultricies quam non laoreet. Suspendisse ut odio vitae eros bibendum aliquam. Phasellus quis sapien leo, vel consequat massa. Duis vel suscipit lorem. Nam eu urna id leo molestie ullamcorper eget id eros. Aenean venenatis mattis lorem, a elementum odio accumsan et. Suspendisse cursus metus feugiat tortor molestie vitae porta sapien ultricies. Fusce malesuada sodales commodo. </p>
                                <a class="pull-right" href="#">Read More --></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="sci">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span4">
                                <h3 class="cPink">Science Article Title</h3>
                                <p>Sed bibendum ultricies quam non laoreet. Suspendisse ut odio vitae eros bibendum aliquam. Phasellus quis sapien leo, vel consequat massa. Duis vel suscipit lorem. Nam eu urna id leo molestie ullamcorper eget id eros. Aenean venenatis mattis lorem, a elementum odio accumsan et. Suspendisse cursus metus feugiat tortor molestie vitae porta sapien ultricies. Fusce malesuada sodales commodo. </p>
                                <a class="pull-right" href="#">Read More --></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divider-vertical"></div>
                            <div class="span4">
                                <h3 class="cPink">Science Article Title</h3>
                                <p>Sed bibendum ultricies quam non laoreet. Suspendisse ut odio vitae eros bibendum aliquam. Phasellus quis sapien leo, vel consequat massa. Duis vel suscipit lorem. Nam eu urna id leo molestie ullamcorper eget id eros. Aenean venenatis mattis lorem, a elementum odio accumsan et. Suspendisse cursus metus feugiat tortor molestie vitae porta sapien ultricies. Fusce malesuada sodales commodo. </p>
                                <a class="pull-right" href="#">Read More --></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divider-vertical"></div>
                            <div class="span4">
                                <h3 class="cPink">Science Article Title</h3>
                                <p>Sed bibendum ultricies quam non laoreet. Suspendisse ut odio vitae eros bibendum aliquam. Phasellus quis sapien leo, vel consequat massa. Duis vel suscipit lorem. Nam eu urna id leo molestie ullamcorper eget id eros. Aenean venenatis mattis lorem, a elementum odio accumsan et. Suspendisse cursus metus feugiat tortor molestie vitae porta sapien ultricies. Fusce malesuada sodales commodo. </p>
                                <a class="pull-right" href="#">Read More --></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where is the 'tabs' `<div>` that you speak of? Is there any other `CSS` related to your question that you haven't shared already?

Comment: i pasted the code up, it was a bootstrap tab class
i tried adding clear:both or other stuff like no floats
thinking that it was due to those things.. but didn't workout

Comment: Here is a fiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/pkhYb/1/ Apart from the fact that the tabs don't work, what is your problem? I'm finding it hard to see where there's any overlap

Comment: O THANKS i was looking for that website!
the masonry div is ONTOP of the tab divs. Overlaping eachother
i used a very bad fix of raping another div outside and absulte the positioning... : (